# Posting "News Feed" messages to facebook from an iPhone application

Tags: ios, facebook, url, social-networking

Is there a simple link to open Facebook in Safari with some text for people to post on their "News Feed"?

Comment: Note, I'm trying to use http://getsharekit.com now. If I like it I'll update this question with that as the solution.

Comment: Facebook does not permit applications to prefill post text. So while I don't know the answer to your question, I do know that if you accomplish this and get caught facebook will disable your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You totally want to check this out:

[facebook-ios-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk)

It is an open source library for the iPhone that lets you do just that!

Comment: getsharekit looks like a great kit - but I have as of yet been unable to actually post to FaceBook or Twitter with it - due to two unrelated problems. Please tell me if you get it to work!

Comment: I can't get it to work with an EAGLView. It's a massive pain. I'm trying to switch between the EAGLView and an UINavigationController which I assume will work but I don't know how to do that. I've only used a navigation controller from a navigation based application with it set up for me.

Comment: I didn't use a UINavigation Controller with it. Instead of passing the whole UINavigationController like it said in the docs, I just called: [actionSheet showInView:[self view]] which worked fine - so I used it with just a plain 'ol UIView.

Comment: Didn't work with me. I'm trying to change the code, bypassing the action sheet all together. It's badly written software that is proving very hard to get working.

Comment: I can;t even find what methods are called when you cancel each part.